# Is the browser supposed to zoom images in the same proportion than others elements?

Tags: html, css

The div elements on the left side appear to be aligned with the alternating colors in the background image on the right.

But when the browser's zoom is changed, the background image is re-sized in a different proportion than the div elements.

**Html:**

```
<div class=dhx_scale_holder style="background-image: none; width: 65px;">
  <div class="dhx_scale_hour">12:00 AM</div>
  <div class="dhx_scale_hour">1:00 AM</div>
  <div class="dhx_scale_hour">2:00 AM</div>
</div>
<div class="dhx_scale_holder " style="left: 75px;"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.dhx_scale_holder {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 74px;
    background-image: url("http://i40.tinypic.com/dpwvfk.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-right-style: dotted;
    border-right-color: #586a7e;    
    height: 1440px;
}

.dhx_scale_hour {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 40px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: dotted;
    background-color: rgb(194, 213, 252);
    height: 59px;
    width: 65px;
}
```

**JSFiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/KuAnW/

(You will have to play with the zoom of your browser to reproduce it)

[image: Browser zoom at 100%]
[image: Browser zoom at 150%]

All the browsers I have tested seems to do the same, with different proportions between the background image and elements though.

Is there anyway to fix this, with minimal changes to the layout (it is generated by a schedule tool), ideally only with css? Javascript would be ok too.

Could you confirm that images do not necessarily scale to the same size than others elements and so this is the expected behavior?

Comment: I'll try a different unit for the font-size, like em.

Comment: Changing the font-size to em didn't work

Comment: Instead of doing this with a background image, why not make it a table?

Comment: the html is generated by a library

Comment: It works for me in Google Chrome! Zooms just fine.. https://www.dropbox.com/s/r2azd3e3mv08u1s/Screenshot%202013-10-02%2015.12.54.png

Comment: I think the first rows don't look so bad, the difference is higher in the last ones (e.g. 11 PM, 12 PM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this is due to rounding error. When you resize 24 "dhx_scale_hour" elements the browser is rounding to the nearest pixel when determining their individual size. Thus it would not resize in exactly the same way as the single "dhx_scale_holder" element (which is only rounded once). This is why they appear to be resizing properly at the top of the chart, but fall out of step as the error of single pixels builds up at the bottom. This is also why it works fine at integer zooms like 200%.

I think a table would be the most appropriate formatting here. Both the hour and holder elements could be td elements, and all browsers would be able to handle the zooming.